# Configuring QtMobility in Carbide.c++

Tags: qt, symbian, qt-mobility

I have installed Carbide.c++, it runs well both in Simulator and my device, but I don't know how to include the **QtMobility** libraries in Carbide.

I have downloaded [Symbian^3 SDK 1.0](http://www.developer.nokia.com) and [QtMobility 1.1.3 source](http://qt.nokia.com/products/qt-addons/mobility/) from Nokia, but am unable to locate QtMobility in Symbian SDK. How can I find/use it?

Comment: Have you followed [these instructions](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/installation.html#building-for-symbian-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to download and install Qt Creator in order to develop Qt apps in Symbian